# Displaying multiple pictures on the same page in a QGIS3x Report

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, atlas, reports

I am reporting on a project which has a series of transects around the perimeter of the site.  For each transect I have prepared a detail plan and cross-section.  Each transect is associated with a series of aerial photographs.  I would like to create a report which includes a series of photos in, say, a 6x4 grid associated with each transect.

I have created a report with a Group 'Transects' which iterates through each transect as expected.  I have created a subgroup 'Transect Photos' which iterates through the relevant photos but which creates a separate page for each photograph.  I would like to produce several distinct photos on each page but cant figure out how to structure the expression to sequence through each photo.
I am using geocoded points as the photos layer and each point is referenced to the relevant transect.  I can also successfully insert the relevant images in both the picture viewer and the HTML frame (see below).

[image: Test Output]

The picture frame includes the following data defined over ride

```sql
CASE
WHEN "Cnge" = attribute(@atlas_feature,'Cnge') THEN "photo"
END
```

Which correctly selects the relevant photos but on separate pages. I don't know how to modify the code so that image 1 is record 1 and image 2 record 2 etc.  My feeling is that a HTML frame may be the right solution but I will still need to work out how to iterate through the photos in code.

How can I do this?

Comment: One possibility would be to use several columns in each Transect Photos dataset, like photo1, photo2,  photo3...

Comment: I could make that work but I am sure that there is a more elegant solution in code..

Comment: Actually this doesn't work as the report engine iterates through all the features in the group layer.  Any other suggestions?